# Plotting outcome estimates from multiple models in the same plot, sort estimates according to group and tidying model outputs

Tags: r, ggplot2, stargazer

I would like to plot multiple models in the same plot. But to have the models sorted/grouped in "categories" on the plot, and not according to the independent variable (treatment, dummy 0-1) which is the same in all models.

In the solution below, it is unclear to where the model coefficient is plotted and if they are in the correct group. I would to keep it in the ggplot2 "environment".

```
rm(list=ls())

# Load packages
library(lfe)
library(dotwhisker)
library(broom)
library(dplyr)
library(stargazer)

set.seed(7)

# Create df. Panel data in long format. One observation equals one county-year
year <- c(2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010,
          2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2012)
county <- c("county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5", 
            "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5",
            "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5",
            "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5",
            "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5",
            "county1", "county2", "county3", "county4", "county5")

treatment <- sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size = 30)

roads_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
schools_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
elder_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
leisure_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
police_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
administrative_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)
libraries_accounts <- runif(30, -100, 100)

roads_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
schools_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
elder_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
leisure_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
police_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
administrative_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)
libraries_budget <- runif(30, -100, 100)

D <- data.frame(year, county, treatment, roads_accounts, schools_accounts, elder_accounts, leisure_accounts, 
                police_accounts, administrative_accounts, libraries_accounts, roads_budget, schools_budget,
                elder_budget, leisure_budget, police_budget, administrative_budget, libraries_budget)


# Estimate models, 14 models in total 
model.list = vector(mode = "list", length = 14) 
j = 1 
for (i in c("roads_accounts", "schools_accounts", "elder_accounts", "leisure_accounts", 
            "police_accounts", "administrative_accounts", "libraries_accounts", "roads_budget", 
            "schools_budget", "elder_budget", "leisure_budget", "police_budget", "administrative_budget", 
            "libraries_budget"))
{
  temp.dta = data.frame(y = D[, i], D[, (!colnames(D) %in%  c("roads_accounts", "schools_accounts", "elder_accounts", "leisure_accounts", 
                                                              "police_accounts", "administrative_accounts", "libraries_accounts", "roads_budget", 
                                                              "schools_budget", "elder_budget", "leisure_budget", "police_budget", "administrative_budget", 
                                                              "libraries_budget"))]) 
  model.list[[j]] <- felm(y ~ treatment | factor(county) + factor(year) | 0 | county, data = temp.dta) 
  j = j + 1 
}

# Plot models 
p <- dwplot(model.list)

category <- rep(c("Account numbers", "Budget numbers"), 7)
groups <- rep(c("Roads", "Schools", "Elderly", "Leisure", "Police", "Administrative", "Libraries"), 2)


p$layers <- lapply(p$layers, function(x) {
  x$data$model <- category 
  x$data$term <- groups
  x})

p + scale_color_manual(values = c("red4", "blue4")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

My output:

[image]

I do not understand the order that the groups appear in. I specified it as "Roads", "Schools", "Elderly", "Leisure", "Police" etc., however, the groups appear in a different order on the graph. So it is unclear to me whether the group represents the correct models (i.e. account and budget numbers for e.g. Roads). I'm pretty sure it is not correct atm

In addition to a figure, I am trying to figure out how to extract information from the models in a tidy output like a dataframe, where I can do some statistics across the models, e.g. finding the median coefficient etc, and create a stargazer table with basic statistics from all the models. I have tried this so far:

```
# tidy(model.list) # Does not work since it is a list, so: 

lapply(model.list, tidy, conf.int = TRUE) # this works. Now I need to save it somehow and get the statistics that I need. 

## create a df and/or stargazer table with the tidy model output. Including the following as columns: outcome; coefficient; SEs; P-values; CIs and number of observations, N: 

df_models <- model.list %>%
  lapply(model.list, tidy, conf.int = TRUE) ## Does not work

stargazer(model.list, type = "text") ## Works but wrong output
```

Answer (score 0):

`dwplot` produces a ggplot, and the problem with convenience functions like this is that you gain ease-of-use but lose the ability to fully customize your output.

If `dwplot` it does not lay out your ggplot the way you want, your options are to either:

1. Respecify your models.
2. Extract the model coefficients from the model and build the plot manually.
3. Try to coerce `dwplot` to plot your models the way you want.
4. Change the ggplot object to conform to your requirements.

I assume you don't want to re-specify your models, and from looking at the docs, it's probably not possible to get `dwplot` to change its output to the one you want. Of the two remaining options, the one that requires least code is probably number 4; that is, change the ggplot object.

First store the `dwplot` output:

```r
p <- dwplot(model.list)
```

Now define your "colour groups" and your "y axis groups" as vectors in the order you want them to appear on the plot.

```
colors <- rep(c("1", "2"), 3)
groups <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)
```

The tricky bit comes in writing these into the plot layers:

```r
p$layers <- lapply(p$layers, function(x) {
  x$data$model <- colors 
  x$data$term <- groups
  x})
```

Now we can plot our result, and add a colour scheme, a theme, and a vertical line at x = 0, as in the desired plot.

```
p + scale_color_manual(values = c("red4", "blue4")) + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = 2) + 
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan. It seems like that solution 4) that you show is the "hacky" solution to the problem. Could you perhaps outline how you would go about: 2) Extract the model coefficients from the model and build the plot manually. Do you loose any of ability to costumize the figure/ggplot2 object in solution 4, compared to solution 2?

Comment: @pheb you are right - it _is_ a hacky solution, because `dwplot` simply doesn't produce the output you are looking for. The non-hacky way is to extract the coefficients from your models into a tidy data frame and plot them yourself. This requires a bit more work and data wrangling, but would be the "proper" way to do it.

Comment: Option 4 is still a ggplot, and you retain the ability to change colours, and theme elements, as well as add other layers on top such as annotations, further geoms etc.

Comment: I am afraid the solution does not work for my application yet. I have tried updating the question with a more specific example of what I am trying and your solution so far. I think the coefficients from the outcomes are not plotted correctly, according to their groups, and it is difficult to see what coefficients belong to which model to validate.